# Is $(N(A)^{\perp})^{\perp}=N(A)$ true in general?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Is $(N(A)^{\perp})^{\perp}=N(A)$ true in general?
I was trying to solve an example where I need to find a matrix so that it's image is the same as $ker(A)$.
I know that $N(A)^{\perp}=R(A^T)$ but is $N(A)=R(A^T)^{\perp}$?

Comment: $(A^\perp)^{\perp}=A$ iff $A$ is a subspace.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: "finite-dimensional" subspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In finite dimension, and for real operators, yes.

If you consider arbitrary Hilbert spaces, then the double orthogonal of the kernel is the closure of the kernel. The kernel will always be closed if $A$ is bounded, so your equality holds for any bounded operator. The key fact is that, in general, 
$$
N(A)^\perp=\overline{R(A^*)},
$$
and the double orthogonal of a subspace is the closure.

Comment: So for finite-dimensional,real matrices is true that $N(A)=R(A^T)^{\perp}$?

Comment: Yes. Every finite-dimensional subspace is closed.